# Why is my discord bot not giving a role to someone who joins?

Tags: python, discord.py

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is online')

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name='member')
    await client.add_roles(member, role)

client.run("token")
```

When I run the bot and someone joins nothing happens.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As it is most likely that you are running discord python 1.5.0 or above, please make sure to actually pass the initialised intents to the client.

```py
client = commands.Bot(
  command_prefix='.',
  intents=intents,
)
```

Comment: File "auto.py", line 31, in on_member_join
    await client.add_roles(member, role)
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'add_roles'

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```py
await member.add_roles(role)
```